# Concatenating files in a directory and finding total number of lines

Tags: bash

In bash:

I am trying to merge all the files in a directory then count the total number of lines all using one command. I realize that I can use | to pipe two commands:

```
! cat /data/files *.txt >> mergedfile.txt | wc -l ~/data/files/mergedfile.txt
```

However, this does not seem to work. I am using bash and running in iPython (thus the ! in front).

Comment: Do not pipe the commands. Replace the `|` by a `;`. That way one command will fill the file correctly and then the number of lines is counted.

Comment: John, please do not [repeat your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391505/117549)

Comment: You should consider registering your account if you're unable to edit your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little garbled:

- Are you using `!` to represent your shell prompt? 
  That’s atypical.
- Are you talking about all the `.txt` files in the `/data/files` directory? 
  To do that, you should say `/data/files/*.txt`. 
  If you mean something else by `/data/files *.txt`, please explain it.
- `>> mergedfile.txt` will *append* the files to `mergedfile.txt`,
  if it already exists. 
  Is that what you want? 
  If you want something like that, you should say so in your question.

Anyway, as stated [by Arrow in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391517/80216#comment697920_391517),
the simple, obvious solution is to replace the `|` with a `;`, like this:

```
$ cat /data/files/*.txt >> mergedfile.txt; wc -l mergedfile.txt
```

Notes:

- As I stated above,
  `>>` appends the files to `mergedfile.txt` if it already exists. 
  If you want to ignore (discard) any previous contents of `mergedfile.txt`,
  use `>` instead of `>>`.
- If you’re going to refer to the same file multiple times,
  you should do it the same way every time. 
  Using a relative pathname one time and an absolute pathname the next time
  is confusing and error-prone. 
  (You might want to simplify things
  by assigning the name of the file to a variable.)

A slight improvement on the above is:

```
$ cat /data/files/*.txt > mergedfile.txt  &&  wc -l mergedfile.txt
```

with `&&` instead of `;`. 
This causes the `wc -l` command to execute
only if the `cat` command succeeds.

Each of the above command lines is characterized as a “command list”,
containing two “pipelines” (although there are no actual pipes involved). 
If you want to do this as a single “pipeline”, do this:

```
$ cat /data/files/*.txt | tee mergedfile.txt | wc -l
```

which counts the lines *while it concatenates the files,*
eliminating the need to read the output file. 
If you want to append to an existing `mergedfile.txt`, use `tee -a`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
! cat /data/files/*.txt >> mergedfile.txt && wc -l /data/files/mergedfile.txt
```

Your commands consists of two commands
- the first one is `cat`, which outputs to a text file by redirection
- the second one is to calculate the length of the resulting file

These two commands need to run in sequence provided the first succeeds. So you use `&&` to chain then. After the `stdout` of `cat` be redirected to `mergedfile.txt`, the command `cat` does not produce `stdout` for piping to `wc`. So using `|` there is wrong.

**Alternatively**, you can do:

```
! cat /data/files/*.txt | wc -l
```

which is more concise and avoids using a temporary file. Here the output of `cat` is sent to `wc` for counting directly.

**Note**, the first approaching using a temporary file has many drawbacks:

- you need to empty the file `mergedfile.txt` before executing it. If you started without that file in your working directory, that is fine. But it is very common that you tried some commands (like the wrong one you used) first and then you forget to empty the temporary file and run the correct command. It will still result in a wrong answer. Indeed, if all the lines are in `/data/files/*.txt`, you can simply use `>` instead of `>>`. It will empty the file first.
- during the execution of the command, the temporary file may be altered by other users, or by yourself when you wants to do something in parallel.

**In addition:** if you need `mergedfile.txt` for later use, you can use `tee` to make a copy of the output:

```
! cat /data/files/*.txt | tee mergedfile.txt | wc -l
```

where `tee` put its `stdin` into `mergedfile.txt` and duplicate it to `stdout`.